# Working PySide example of Qt diagram editor?

Tags: qt, pyside, diagram

When running the [PySide Diagram Scene example](https://github.com/nicoddemus/PySide-Examples/tree/master/examples/graphicsview/diagramscene) (circa 2010), I get the error below. Is there a more current example of a basic diagram editor available?

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/dle/Documents/Programming/Python/diagramscene.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dle/Documents/Programming/Python/diagramscene.py", line 11, in <module>
import diagramscene_rc
  File "C:\Users\dle\Documents\Programming\Python\diagramscene_rc.py", line 404, in <module>
qInitResources()
  File "C:\Users\dle\Documents\Programming\Python\diagramscene_rc.py", line 399, in qInitResources
QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)
TypeError: 'qRegisterResourceData' called with wrong argument types:
  qRegisterResourceData(int, str, str, str)
Supported signatures:
  qRegisterResourceData(int, unicode, unicode, unicode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file diagramscene_rc.py has been generated for python2, to solve it you must recompile that file for it opens a terminal in the folder and executes the following command:

```
pyside-rcc diagramscene.qrc -o diagramscene_rc.py -py3
```

Or, place the letter b before assigning the variable as shown below:

```
qt_resource_data = "\
\x00\x00\x01\x12\ 
...
qt_resource_name = "\
\x00\x06\
...
qt_resource_struct = "\
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\
....
```

to:

```
qt_resource_data = b"\
\x00\x00\x01\x12\ 
...
qt_resource_name = b"\
\x00\x06\
...
qt_resource_struct = b"\
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\
....
```

Comment: Thank you. The example now runs. The resource file provides Qt icons and components in a binary form?